# Packages for import android.net.http.RequestQueue;

Tags: java, android

I have a problem while using the following import functions..Can any1 help me how to solve it

```
import android.net.http.RequestQueue;  
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

My intent is to send a tweet using Android..

Comment: What is the problem, does the compiler complain about the statements? If so, what does it say?

Comment: yup...It says
"The import android.net.http.RequestQueue cannot be resolved"
Should I include any packages?

Answer (score 1):

android.net.http.RequestQueue doesn't exist.

[API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/package-summary.html)

Comment: How to resolve the problem..
I copied the source code from
 http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/24/
Pls tel me how to resolve the error

Comment: @Saranya.R: You cannot "resolve the error". The snippet you are using is old and flawed. It also will not work starting in 16 days, once Twitter discontinues basic authentication and switches to OAuth. You need to find a more current example.

Comment: Okay can u tel me how to tweet using Android?